# "Ambiguous redirect" error when executing a script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In the below code snippet, I keep getting this error message:

```
#!/bin/sh
java -jar /opt/wiremock/wiremock-standalone-2.7.1.jar -port 9393 --container-threads 200  --verbose >> /opt/wiremock/wiremock.log 2>&1
```

Error:

```
bash: /opt/wiremock/script.sh: line 2: 1#015: ambiguous redirect
Feb  8 17:11:27 ssa2 systemd: wiremock.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb  8 17:11:27 ssa2 systemd: Unit wiremock.service entered failed state.
Feb  8 17:11:27 ssa2 systemd: wiremock.service failed.**
```

I have tried commenting out the redirection as in:

```
java -jar /opt/wiremock/wiremock-standalone-2.7.1.jar -port 9393 --container-threads 200  --verbose #>> /opt/wiremock/wiremock.log 2>&1
```

and it works properly. However, I would like to make the redirection work so that I have the logs in the specified file.

Comment: How do you run your script?

Comment: actually restart the service and this script is triggered [Service] User=root WorkingDirectory=/opt/wiremock ExecStart=/bin/bash /opt/wiremock/script.sh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line of your error message is telling you that you have a carriage return at the end of your line.

You have several ways to solve the problem:

1. Make sure your script has unix-style line endings (eg. dos2unix)
2. Add a statement terminator to the end of each command, such as: `; #`